# bi-Storage tri-Storage java shortcuts?

Tags: java, syntax, consumer

As we can use BiConsumer< T, T> and TriConsumer< T, T, T> to substitute for functional interfaces, is there a substitute for storage classes?

For example:

```
public class Storage {
    public Storage(Object a, Object b){ 
        //storage substitute for Bi-
    }
    public Storage(Object a, Object b, Object c){ 
        //storage substitute for Tri-
    }
}
```

in the form of a java util already established? i.e

```
BiStorage<Object, Object>
```

or

```
TriStorage<Object, Object, Object>
```

Comment: Is `Storage` your own class?

Comment: Yes, as an example. I want to know if this kind of OOP already exists in java

Answer (score 0):

```
List#of //  in java-9
Arrays.asList // for lower than java-9
Object[] // arrays can't use generics, but can be cast to a generic type
Map.SimpleEntry // for two entries when they might differ
Map.entry // since java-9
```

Otherwise there is also the `Pair` from apache and a lot of other projects - but creating such classes is more than trivial anyway...

Comment: We might get value types in Java-12, which would make such Pair classes useless :)

Comment: @Lino me confused, how would value types make `Pair` useless? :|

Comment: As `Pair` only holds a left and a right value it can be substituted by a `value`-type which doesn't have as much overhead

Comment: @Lino I admit that I understand value types not as much as I would want to - but it simply means headerless objects in my understanding, where `==` could be used instead of `equals`. Pair would still be needed, you would still code with a `Pair`, it's just that internally it would be treated differently.

Comment: I myself still have some problems wrapping my head around value types. I think of them as primitve objects. I might have made my point not clear enough. I meant te use of `Pair`-class, would by useless, whereas the use of a `Pair`-value type is prefered

Comment: @Lino well, in this case, I will agree - but only if such value types classes are added into the jdk itself. And that btw, would still be a class AFAIK

Comment: Exactly, but I assume that this will not happen. And every project and framework will continue to have some sort of tuple object / value type :|

Comment: @Lino that brings an interesting point - will we be able to annotate, implements marker, etc - to create values types? :)

Comment: That would be quite interesting, and useful. It would also be nice to know if you could make generic value types

Comment: Just to note that while `List.of` can certainly be used instead of `Arrays.asList` for most cases that `Arrays.asList` is used for they are not totally the same thing. The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is fixed-sized but _writable_; and writes actually mutate the array used to create it. Whereas the `List` returned by `List.of` is _read-only_ and creates a copy of the array used to create it.